# How to replace an special character?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, char

I am working on an excel vba macro which opens some files but I ran into a problem, some files have a special character and I cannot copy it to be able to make a replacement, I even tried to find the ASCII code but it throws me the same code as the common space, I can only see it in MS Word.

The tiny circle is the special char:

[image]

Comment: I think it is `chr(176)`

Comment: No it's not, its not a degree character, its an invisible one.

Comment: Perhaps it's a non-breaking space (160)

Comment: "some files" - what kind of files specifically?

Comment: @TimWilliams Excel books, is that relevant?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Maybe it is a medium small white circle -- unicode `26AC` or `9900`.  If not, if you could copy/paste the symbol into your original question,  perhaps we can figure it out.  But usually, in Excel, if you look for ASCII code when it is really Unicode, the return value is `63`, not `32` as you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recognize characters in Word:

```vb
Sub PrintASCII()
    s = Selection.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Debug.Print Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Usage: select the symbols and run this Sub. See output in VBE Immediate window

[image]

**Output**

```
 95 
 95 
 95 
 95 
 160 
 95 
 95 
 95 
 95 
 95 
 13
```